# Connecting couchbase with nodejs - invalid_argument

Tags: node.js, couchbase

```js
async function cb() {
  const clusterConnStr = "couchbases://localhost:8091";
  const username = "Administrator";
  const password = "xxx";
  try {
    const cluster = await couchbase.connect(clusterConnStr, {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      timeouts: {
        kvTimeout: 10000, // milliseconds
      },
    });
    console.log("Connected....");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

cb();
```

I am getting the following error.

```js
[Error: invalid_argument] { code: 3 }
```

Couchbase version

```js
"couchbase": "^4.1.2"
```

Couchbase is working locally
[image]

Not sure why I am getting this error, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mostly right the only issue is your placement or parameter values can you try like this:

```
async function cb() {
  const clusterConnStr = "couchbase://127.0.0.1/?connectionTimeout=1200";
  const username = "Administrator";
  const password = "xxx";
  try {
    const cluster = await couchbase.connect(clusterConnStr, {
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
    console.log("Connected....");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still i am having the same issue

Comment: Hmmm I see people having some error realted to this there is another option to set timeout you can pass it in parameter check the edited answer

Comment: I can not see any other option to pass timeout

Comment: Yes I see many people having issue with parameter either you can downgrade you current version or use with parameter :|

Comment: Can you please send me any references link for parameters for newer version?

Comment: Yeah here it is you can set timeout with every collection request:https://forums.couchbase.com/t/connect-timeout-in-node-js-sdk-3-0/28255/2